# Driver class path in spark/hive

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hive

I'm working on an application using `Spark 2.2.0` and trying to prepare its distribution with `maven-assembly-plugin/maven-shade-plugin/maven-jar-plugin`. I'm starting my spark context as follows:

```
SparkSession.builder
          .enableHiveSupport()
          .getOrCreate()
```

I tried to cases:

I. ***Fat jar.*** Building fat jar and putting there all dependencies, application classes and configurations. I then run this application as follows: `/usr/bin/spark-submit --class some.pack.age.Main --master yarn --deploy-mode client --executor-memory 4G --num-executors 1 /path/to/the/fat/jar/fat.jar`. And it works pretty much fine.

II. ***Preparing distribution.*** I prepared the following distribution:

```
 |-- conf
 |   |-- log4j
 |   |   `-- log4j.properties
 |   `-- main.conf
 `-- lib
     |-- all-dependecies.jar
     `-- app.jar
```

I then tried to run it

`/usr/bin/spark-submit --driver-class-path /som/path/conf --class some.pack.age.Main --master yarn --deploy-mode client --executor-memory 4G --num-executors 1 --jars __paths_to_the_two_jars__`
I then got the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.connectionpool.DatastoreDriverNotFoundException: 
The specified datastore driver ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") was not found in the CLASSPATH. 
Please check your CLASSPATH specification, and the name of the driver.
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.connectionpool.AbstractConnectionPoolFactory.loadDriver(AbstractConnectionPoolFactory.java:58)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.connectionpool.BoneCPConnectionPoolFactory.createConnectionPool(BoneCPConnectionPoolFactory.java:54)
        at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.generateDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:238)
        ... 109 more
```

Why is that in the first case the driver is in classpath, but in the second is not?

Comment: what is the difference between your fat.jar and "all-dependecies.jar". ? And what does "app.jar" contains? Does "all-dependecies.jar" not contain the classes that are in "app.jar". Share how you are preparing your distribution

Comment: @AmitKumar Actually, the issue was about `spark-defaults.conf`. I just overwrite the classpath put there.